# Face is not drawn

Tags: three.js

I try to draw a mesh with several faces.

Some of the faces are drawn some of them not.

When instantiating a mesh which is normally not drawn,
with the index in reverse it is drawn.

The following doesnt work:

```
   geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(k,k+1,k+2,myface.normal));
```

This works:

```
   geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(k+2,k+1,k,myface.normal));
```

This for me means that the order of the vertices is
wrong and so the normal is drawn in the opposite direction,
but I pass the correct normal to the face (which I calculate myself)
Even if I try to negate the normal, the face is not drawn.

So if I pass the correct normal as I understand it, it would make
no difference if the indices are put in reverse or otherwise.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The face front is determined by the winding order, not the face normal. The default winding order is counter-clockwise (CCW).

Have a look at the source of `Geometry.computeFaceNormals()`, and notice how the computed face normal is consistent with a CCW winding order.

three.js r.58