# three.js visualizing wrongly with obj while other 3D visualizer software correct

Tags: three.js

I recently encounter a really weird bug.

let me show you some pictures first.

pictures below are rendered result w.r.t same .obj mesh from different software.

1. from 3D builder in win10

   [image: check here......]
2. from three.js

   [image: check here]

please ignore the color difference, you may notice the position of the box object is different and the file object falling to pieces.

I use OBJLoader to load this .obj file.

it's not the weird part yet, **what confuse me is that this obj is a subset of another obj, and in this obj, it actually has 14 objects, and the box and the file is the only two have problems**

I've also confirm with MeshLab and blender, results from 3D builder is right.

The loading code I use is something like:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    loader.load('meshes/test.obj',function(object){
        console.log(object);
        var divWidth = 320;
        var divHeight = 240;
        // camera is globally uniform
         var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30,divWidth/divHeight,0.1,1000);
         camera.position.set(0,0,1);
         camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);

        // geometry of objects also global
        var geo;

        var container = document.getElementById('test');
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({preserveDrawingBuffer: true });
        renderer.setSize(divWidth,divHeight);
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);



        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors});
        for(i=0;i<objCount;i++){
            geo=new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(object.children[i].geometry);
            j=0;
            var temp=[];
            for(var k=0;k<geo.faces.length;k++){
                temp=objRoughRGB[i][j]; // objRoughRGB has every vertex rgb info, pre-read
                geo.faces[k].vertexColors[0]=new THREE.Color(temp[0],temp[1],temp[2]);
                j++;
                temp=objRoughRGB[i][j];
                geo.faces[k].vertexColors[1]=new THREE.Color(temp[0],temp[1],temp[2]);
                j++;
                temp=objRoughRGB[i][j];
                geo.faces[k].vertexColors[2]=new THREE.Color(temp[0],temp[1],temp[2]);
                j++;
            }
            geo.colorsNeedUpdate=true;
            geo.elementsNeedUpdate=true;
            object.children[i].geometry=geo;
            object.children[i].material=material;
        }
        console.log(object);
        console.log(object.children[0].geometry.vertices);
        scene.add(object);

       renderer.render(scene,camera);
    });
});
```

I hope I have made myself clear.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

I don't know how to share a model on SO,
but I once shared the model on three.js github issue, because I do find it may be a bug. you can find it in the end of issue, test.zip. [check here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12220)

Comment: Are you able to share the model? Or, if not, a simpler model that still reproduces the problem?

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Thanks for your attention! 
Yes, just one box model or file object model still have this problem, actually the tote object model is fine, I just add the tote to enhance the contrast.
I don't know how to share a model on SO, but I once shared the model on three.js github issue, because I do find it may be a bug. you can find it in the end of issue, test.zip. [check here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12220)

Comment: The winding order of some of your faces is reversed. Set `material.side = THREE.DoubleSide`,

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks, West, the problem is solved, I have a follow up question, how do I know "some faces are reversed", I mean all faces are in right winding order or all wrong is clear to identify. Is it due to my object mesh points are not properly sorted? If it's a trivial question, could you please tell me which keyword to search in Google? Thanks again!

Comment: Lean about face culling and winding order. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640089/face-is-not-drawn/17640540#17640540